# Trying to create timeAgo function for news feed, but it just displays "0 seconds ago"

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, time

I am trying to create a newsfeed that shows something like "3 minutes ago" or whatever the current time is from when they posted. However, very time I post to the newsfeed it just says 0 seconds ago. Could someone please tell me where my code is messing up.

```
func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {

        let secondsAgo = Int(Date().timeIntervalSinceNow)

        if secondsAgo < 60 {
            return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < 60 * 60 {
            return "\(secondsAgo / 60) minutes ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < 60 * 60 * 24 {
            return "\(secondsAgo / 60 / 60) hours ago"
        }

        return "\(secondsAgo / 60 / 60 / 24) days ago"
    }
```

Comment: You are initializing new Date() object each tame so it gives you the current time. Also instead of calculating it this way, there is ready built-in API for this kind of time presentation: DateComponentsFormatter

Comment: You should provide date at which news feed is posted as an input to this function. Where is that date stored now?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Date()` returns the **current date**, you need to specify an input value with the type `Date` for the function and use the `timeIntervalSinceNow` property of that value.

Also, you need to multiply the value you're getting with -1, since the value will be **negative** if the input date is from the past.

```
func timeAgoDisplay(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let secondsAgo = Int(date.timeIntervalSinceNow) * -1
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am relatively new to swift programming. Here is what I put but it still doesn't seem to be working.

func timeAgoDisplay(_ date: Date) -> String {
       
        let secondsAgo = Int(date.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        
        if secondsAgo < 60 {
            return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < 60 * 60 {
            return "\(secondsAgo / 60) minutes ago"
        } else if secondsAgo < 60 * 60 * 24 {
            return "\(secondsAgo / 60 / 60) hours ago"
        }
        
        return "\(secondsAgo / 60 / 60 / 24) days ago"
    }

Comment: When I try to call the function is says "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call." I am not sure where or what date value to give it. Is there any chance you could update the code you posted to be exactly what I should write out so I can understand this all better? So if I post to the news feed and then look at that post 15 minutes later it should say "15 minutes ago."

Comment: You should use the function like this: `let timeAgoString = timeAgoDisplay(post.date)`

Comment: It says "Value of type 'Post' has no member 'date'

Comment: This was just an example, I don't know what is the name of the date property. For more information, check out this: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html